# Why administrator user makes the publish field of the node to zero?

Tags: nodes

when I access any node in my system by ADMIN user, after updating the content, it changes the published status of the content to zero. Why is it happening?

Is it something general?!

Comment: No, it's not general. Maybe you have something to do with roles and permissions settings...

Comment: It might be worth checking your modules too. How about making a demo site and test saving a node with all your modules turned off.